# 3D Slam vs. 2D Navigation

Tags: ros, slam, navigation, ros-kinetic, beginner

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

It's a very basic question.

Is it possible to do 3d navigation? (robust using LIDaR).   (other than rtab (focused on lidar data))

There are slam algorithms which are responsible for 3d slam (e.g octomap). But for navigation these algorithms downgrade it to 2D.
In this case why should we do 3d mapping? Is there any benefit of doing so?
I mean at the end if navigation is suppose to be done in 2d; what is the purpose of fancy 3d map?

Many Thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/286286/3d-slam-vs.-2d-navigation/) by [RoboRos](https://answers.ros.org/users/33640/roboros/) on ROS Answers with karma: 37 on 2018-03-22

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi There,
It is a good point to clarify. We use a map to estimate a drivable path in an environment. We can use either 2D or 3D map depending on the application what robot is designed for. If we use 3D motion planning (6 DOF), we definitely need a 3D map to avoid obstacles and reach the goal in a 3D space. However, in most wheel robot applications, a robot is driving on a 2D plane and a 2D map is sufficient to achieve navigation task. For those applications, laser scanners based mapping methods such as Gmapping can be used. In addition, if someone uses an RGB camera like Kinect for mapping, Gmaping may not give an accurate result since, RGBD sensors are low FoV and short-range sensors. But it gives an accurate result with RGBD mapping (3D). Therefore, people use an extracted 2D slice from a 3D map for 2D navigation with path planning algorithms such as A*. On the other hand, a 3D map provides details information on the environment.  Also, it provides registered RGB images at each pose and they can be used for place recognition, and for other decision-making tasks based on the Visual information. Therefore, RGB sensors give more capabilities for 2D navigation.

---

Originally posted by [Gayan Brahmanage](https://answers.ros.org/users/26769/gayan-brahmanage/) with karma: 929 on 2018-03-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 5

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [RoboRos](https://answers.ros.org/users/33640/roboros/) on 2018-03-23**:
Hi, Thanks for your response.
But in case; if we are using a legged robot (not wheeled one) . During navigation; how is it suppose to benefit from the 2d map (as we downgrade the map to 2d for navigation). ?

**Comment by [qinyingying](https://answers.ros.org/users/36508/qinyingying/) on 2018-07-17**:
Hi, I have a problem, Now using ORB_SLAM2 and kinect camera, I can construct the environment map, such as dense pointcloud and octomap, But I don't know how to use this map to navigate. You mentioned  people use an extracted 2D slice from a 3D map for 2D navigation. Can you tell me how to use it ?

**Comment by [RoboRos](https://answers.ros.org/users/33640/roboros/) on 2018-07-22**:
@qinyingying  once you create the octomap. You can save it in 2d by running the command:
rosrun map_server map_saver -f map_name.pgm + 2d_mapping_topic

**Comment by [qinyingying](https://answers.ros.org/users/36508/qinyingying/) on 2018-07-22**:
Can I transfer a octomap to .pgm file by using this command?

**Comment by [qinyingying](https://answers.ros.org/users/36508/qinyingying/) on 2018-07-22**:
thank you for your answer, and what's the meaning of 2d_mapping_topic?

**Comment by [RoboRos](https://answers.ros.org/users/33640/roboros/) on 2018-07-22**:
Yes, definitely, below command will save the 2d map. Make sure that this topic is published though:

```
rosrun map_server map_saver -f map_name.pgm map:=projected_map
```

Can you please explain, how did you safe octomap using orb?

**Comment by [qinyingying](https://answers.ros.org/users/36508/qinyingying/) on 2018-07-22**:
Thankk you for your answer, I will try.
I using the ORB_SLAM2 to obtain keyframe, then I insert the keyframe to octomap.

**Comment by [qinyingying](https://answers.ros.org/users/36508/qinyingying/) on 2018-07-23**:
I tried the map_server, but I can't transfer my octomap to .pgm, the error is **Waiting for the map**.
And my octomap is published in this way,  **octo_pub = nh.advertise<octomap_msgs::Octomap>("/octomap_binary", 1)**.
Can you help me? Thank you in advance.

**Comment by [qinyingying](https://answers.ros.org/users/36508/qinyingying/) on 2018-07-23**:
@RoboRos Thank you in advance.